# In NextJS, how can I show a blob of type 'image/jpeg', received from an API call, on screen?

Tags: javascript, next.js, huggingface

In nextjs, I do the following API call:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/generateimageHG2');
```

this call the following function:

```
import { HfInference } from "@huggingface/inference";


export default async function generate (req, res) {

  try{
  const inference = new HfInference('[token]');
  const response = await inference.textToImage({
      model: "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2",
      inputs: "award winning high resolution photo of a giant dragon/((ladybird)) hybrid, [trending on artstation]",
      parameters: {
          negative_prompt: "blurry",
      },
  });
  
  console.log (response);  
   

    res.status(200).send(response);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error fetching property information: ' + error.message);
  } 
  
};
```

The console log prints the following:

> Blob { size: 93803, type: 'image/jpeg' }

So I know I'm getting a blob.

I'm really stuck in turning this blob into an image on the screen. I tried URL.CreateObjectURL, but that causes an error.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: **Danger!** You've posted your private access token here publicly (the `hf_…` string), meaning anyone can use your account.  You need to invalidate the token and request a new one, and be more careful what you copy & paste in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show a blob in `img` tag directly. You have to convert it to an object url first:

```js
const src = useMemo(() => URL.createObjectURL(blob), [blob]);

<Image src={src} />
```

**note:** I am not sure but you may get a warning or error from NextJS saying that you have to use `img` instead of `Image` in this case. the reason might be that we are not using the real source of the image and NextJS cannot optimize it. If that happened, that's totally okay. you can use `img` tag without any problem

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should prefer using your API route directly in an `<img src="…">` instead of using `fetch` to download the image and then handling the resulting `Blob`.

Dealing with a fetch response yourself is slower and memory-inefficient, and if you just want to display the image, there's no reason to overcomplicate things.

It should be as simple as:

```html
<img src="/api/generateimageHG2">
```